# post status through android on facebook wall

Tags: android

I have an adapter with some items that help to invite friends via mail and facebook. I want to post a status on facebook through browser if facebook application is not installed on the phone and post status through faceboook application if app is available.Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As currently written, its hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: fallow [this](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2011/12/how-to-update-facebook-status-via.html)

Comment: i mean that on click of button i want to post a status on facebook. It should be through browser if facebook app is not installed on the phone and if faceboook application is available on the phone then post through the app.